# Choosing not visible radio button

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

I am using ruby 2.5.1, watir 6.11, Chrome 68.0, chrome webdriver 2.40  for web-scraping and I've got a problem with selecting radio-button. Html code of my page looks like:

```
<tr> <td class="filtr-info">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="filtr-content-radio">
<div class="iradio_square-grey checked" style="position: relative;">
<input id="id1" name="name" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">  
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;">
</ins></div>
<span class="filter-radio-name">KRS</span>
<div class="iradio_square-grey" style="position: relative;">
<input id="id2" name="name" type="radio" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;">
</ins></div>
<span class="filter-radio-name">REGON</span>
<div class="iradio_square-grey" style="position: relative;">
<input id="id3" name="name" type="radio" value="2" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;">
</ins></div>
<span class="filter-radio-name">NIP</span>
</td>
<td class="filtr-help">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

So, I 've got 3 radio buttons and want to select one of them. The problem occurs when I try to use method *set* on of those I receive a following error:

```
unknown error: Element <input id="id1" name="name" type="radio" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"> is not clickable at point (623, 245).
```

I also tried some methods to check how watir sees those buttons:

```
$b.radio(:id,'id1').exists? => true
$b.radio(:id,'id1').present? => false
$b.radio(:id,'id1').visible? => false
$b.radio(:id,'id1').hidden? => false
```

Is there any way I can choose one of buttons if they only exist, but are not visible or present?

Comment: Is it a proper HTML? Because your style attribute of the radio button places all the radio button at the same place one after another. When I remove style attribute, I can look at three radio buttons separately.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I've edited the original post- now you can check with the proper HTML.

Comment: I tried using your code, I am not facing any error. Update the whole error message first, second, take this html snippet and try opening the file and see how it looks. Because none of the radio buttons are not even in the appearance. Or can you provide me the url?

Comment: @Rajagopalan I can't provide the url, as the site requires logging and it's paid service.

Comment: @Rajagopalan whole error:
`
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.13.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': unknown error: Element <input id="id3" name="name" type="radio" value="2" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"> is not clickable at point (604, 329). Other element would receive the click: <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ins` element is overlaying your element and I think it's permanent from your html, you better perform this click, I hope it would work.

```
b.radio(id: 'id2').following_sibling.click
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the radio buttons, check if it is `present?` and then `click` or `set`

```
['id1', 'id2', 'id3'].each do |el_id|
   el = $b.radio(id: el_id)
   el.click if el.present?
end
```

Comment: Each of those buttons are not present, but they exist.